# FBLoginDialog not shown

Tags: iphone

I'm an iphone newb.  I added the following code to my viewDidLoad() method but a blank screen shows up.  What am I doing wrong?

FBSession *session = [FBSession 
             sessionForApplication:@"a31c3e53bba4a5f2b3955d6e5e 876717"
             secret:@"6ecbefa3807406bd13187297e58efae9" delegate:self];

FBLoginDialog* dialog = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] initWithSession:session] autorelease];

[dialog show];

Thanks!

Comment: When you get your answer, you should go change your apps secret key from the facebook developer console, as you've just given it away.

Comment: no I just stole one from another blog post I found :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the code into the AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

the call to [dialog show] has to occur on the main thread (as all UI related calls)